# Simultaneous installation of slurm and pbs pro

Tags: slurm, hpc, pbs

Is it possible to install both Slurm and PBS on the same cluster? We just need it for some comparison benchmarks, and we need to have the same hardware?

And, theoretically speaking, if they can coexist together on the same cluster, can they be used at the same time? If so, how can any one of them realize the effect of the other on the cluster resources (e.g., CPU workload, available memory, etc) for scheduling purpose? and how would any one of them handle requirements like binding a specific core to a specific tasks, in which case, the other work load manager won't be able to use that core?

Regards